# Kendo UI grid prevents updating image column

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am trying a `Kendo UI` grid implementation which has an image column as shown at below:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,                
    pageSize: 10,
    height: 400,
    toolbar: [{ name: "create"}],
    columns: [{
        field: "ImageData", title: "Select Photo", width: 50, 
        template: '<img id="img_${PersonnelId}" src="/Admin/GetPersonnelImage?personnelId=${PersonnelId}" />' },
                    { field: "Name", title: "Name", width: 80 },
                    { field: "SurName", title: "Surname", width: 80 },
                    { field: "isActive", title: "Active", width: 40 },
                    { command: ["edit", "destroy", { name: "Photo", text: "Photo", click: Photo }], title: " ", width: "130px"}],
        editable: "inline",
        remove: function (e) {
             // remove  
        },            
        save: function (e) {
                //save
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Image column template makes `GET` requests to the following `ASP.MVC`action method in order to access its related image from database.

```
public FileContentResult GetPersonnelImage(int personnelId)
{
    Personnel p = personnelRepository.GetById(personnelId);
    if (p != null)
    {
        return File(p.ImageData, p.ImageMimeType);
    }

    return null;            
}
```

As shown above, there is a custom command button named `Photo` which provides user to select an image file on a modal window. Following jQuery function running when user clicks this `submitPhoto` button on modal window:

```
var wnd, uploadTemplate, dataItem;

function Photo(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    wnd.content(uploadTemplate(dataItem));

    $("#imgfile").change(function (evt) {
        var f = evt.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            alert("Selected file does not appear an image file! Please check your selection");
            return;
        }

        reader.onload = function (e) { $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result); };
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    });

    // Updates the src attribute of the grid image column
    $("#submitPhoto").click(function (e) {
        var pid = dataItem.PersonnelId;
        var imgPtr = "#img_" + String(pid);
        var v = $('#preview').attr('src');
        $(imgPtr).attr('src', v);
    });

        wnd.center().open();
    }
```

The `src` attribute of the grid column is updating at the end of the above function.

Everything works fine so far. However, grid makes `GET`requests to the action method immediately when modal window is closed and causes to lose new image selection.

I would like to prevent `GET` requests while user editing data. I don't know what am I doing wrong here. Any suggestions would be really perfect.

Thanks in advance